# Getting an error "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." in React Native when using AXIOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

```
return function (dispatch) {
    Axio_Instance({
            url: '/user/authenticate/',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password,
            }
        }
    ).then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: USER_LOGIN, payload: response});
    }).catch(error => dispatch({type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL, payload: error}))
}
```

I have created an AXIO client towards my API.

```
const Axio_Instance = axios.create({
baseURL: 'localhost:8080/chatapi/',
timeout: 1000,
```

});

and imported as

```
`import axios from 'axios';`
```

I am calling the function like this,

```
                onPress={()=>[enter image description here][1]   this.props.dispatch(login(this.state.username,this.state.password));
                }}>
```

Issue : When I run this in my emulator the above error comes. Please suggest where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Consider using redux-thunk or redux-promise-middleware libraries to handle async action creators. Check out my article here https://medium.com/the-andela-way/async-actions-and-tests-with-redux-promise-middleware-3b6bda8aa83d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux-Promise-Middleware libraries would do the same task. Consider using them.